# How to bind xml data to comboBox for making intelligence?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, combobox

This is my xml file;

```
<UserClass>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>oss</Name>
  <Address>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Street>asstreet</Street>
  </Address>
</UserClass>
```

So I want to add these "nodes" to comboBox items. 
When user typed UserClass and type "."(dot) to end of "UserClass"; Id, Name and other things have to listed in combobox.

User typed "UserClass." and -> combobox get these;

```
UserClass.Id
UserClass.Name
UserClass.Address.Id
UserClass.Address.Street
```

I tried many things, include that one;

```
    ...
    try
    {
        string parsedNode = ParseComboBox();
        XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(_globalXml));

        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(rdr.LocalName);
            }

            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        }



        //string parsedNode = ParseComboBox();
        //XmlNodeList childList = xml.GetElementsByTagName(parsedNode);

        ////comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        //foreach (XmlNode node in childList)
        //{
        //    foreach (var osman in node.ChildNodes)
        //    {
        //        comboBox1.Items.Add(parsedNode + "." + osman);
        //    }
        //}


    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fuuu");
    }
}...

    private string ParseComboBox()
    {
        string resultAsXmlNodes = null;
        string text = comboBox1.Text;

        if (text.EndsWith("."))
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { '.' };

            string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);

            foreach (string s in words)
            {
                resultAsXmlNodes += s;
            }
        }

        return resultAsXmlNodes;
    }
```

It's not working correctly. I believe there is an easy way to do it.
So, what is the simple way? Or simply,
How can I show node names in comboBox ?

Comment: At a quick glance your XML parsing doesn't appear to be correct. Perhaps it would be easier to debug if you separated responsibilities a bit and create a function that will return the desired strings from a given node? Once you have this list, binding it to the ComboBox will be much simpler

Answer (score 1):

I found multiple problems with this. Here's some example code that I got working for a form project with an XML File and one ComboBox control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.KeyDown += comboBox1_KeyDown;
        }

        private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Decimal:
                case Keys.OemPeriod:
                    LoadComboItems(comboBox1.Text);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        void LoadComboItems(string userInput)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            string lookupName = userInput.Trim();
            if (lookupName.Length > 0)
            {
                string _globalXML = Application.StartupPath + @"\XMLFile1.xml";
                XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(_globalXML);

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (rdr.LocalName == lookupName)
                    {
                        string ElementName = "";
                        int eCount = 0;
                        int prevDepth = 0;
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                            {
                                ElementName += '.' + rdr.LocalName;
                                eCount++;
                            }
                            else if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && eCount == rdr.Depth)
                            {
                                if (rdr.Depth >= prevDepth)
                                {
                                    comboBox1.Items.Add(lookupName + ElementName);
                                    int pos = ElementName.LastIndexOf('.');
                                    ElementName = ElementName.Substring(0, pos);
                                    prevDepth = rdr.Depth;
                                }
                                eCount--; 
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                }

                comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ally. Your answer was a solution, it has little bug(When user but . cursor selection move to first character) but it's working. But this is too much code for this job. I'm trying to do solve it with best practices. If you bookmarked or watch this topic, you will see my codes( When I've solved it correctly ). Thank you very much again.